# How to automate a table for using the distributive law

Tags: tables, rules

I am trying to do the following. I thought I should use a new post since the last one very unclear.

I am very grateful for all the help. Thank you

[image]

I am starting with this suggestion and am trying to modify it but it is very difficult to get it to how I want it, the boxes are very narrow and this type of code is hard. I have only used tables.

```
\documentclass[
  a5paper,
  % pagesize,11pt,% both are default and therefore not needed
  bibliography=totoc,% bibtotoc is deprecated and therefore replaced according
                     % to the warning message
  numbers=noenddot,% pointlessnumbers is deprecated and therefore replaced
                   % according to the warning message
  headings=normal,% normalheadings is deprecated and therefore replaced
                  % according to the warning message
  DIV=9,twoside=false,
  headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,% see the KOMA-Script manual
headheight=87pt,% not used, to not lower the header, but this results in a warning
footheight=52pt, % no longer needed, because the lines are not part of the footer
]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{trajan}

\usepackage{setspace}

\linespread{1.05}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}% moved according to the KOMA-Script manual, because it
                      % makes no sense before changing font an linespread.

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[%
  autoenlargeheadfoot=false,% only warn but don't change height reserved for header or footer  
  manualmark,% or maybe automark, this is not clear due to missing information
             % in the question.
  plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,% See the KOMA-Script manual for more information
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a5paper,
 total={100mm,200mm}, %not sue what this line is either.
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=35mm,
 headsep=2mm,
 }

 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{efbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tasks}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\newcounter{example}
\counterwithin*{example}{section}
\newlength \templgtha
\newlength \templgthb
\newlength \templgthc
\newsavebox \tempboxa
\setlength \templgthb {\textwidth}
\setlength \templgthc {\textwidth}
\addtolength \templgthc {-10pt}
\newenvironment{example}{%
  \stepcounter{example}%
  \par\vspace{5pt}\noindent
  \sbox \tempboxa{%
    \efbox[font=\normalfont\bfseries,linecolor=cyan,linewidth=.9pt]{Example~\theexample}%
  }%
  \settowidth \templgtha {\usebox \tempboxa}%
  \addtolength \templgthb {-\templgtha}%
  \usebox \tempboxa
  {\color{cyan}\vrule width\templgthb height0.9pt depth0.3pt}\par\vspace{10pt}\noindent\rmfamily
}{%
  \par\noindent
  {%
    \color{cyan}%
    \vrule width\templgthc height0.3pt depth0.9pt
    \vrule width10pt height2pt depth2pt
  }\par
}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\color{black}}c}
\renewcommand\theadalign{CCC}
\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \begin{tasks}
    \task $(x+2)(x+3)$
    \begin{center}
      \color{red}
      \begin{tabular}{%
          *{3}{!{\vrule width 1pt}C}!{\vrule width 1pt}
        }
        \Xcline{2-3}{1pt}
        \multicolumn{1}{c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{\thead{$\times$}} & \thead{$x$} & \phantom{xxx} \thead{$2$} \phantom{xxx}\\\Xhline{1pt}
        \thead{$x$} & $x^{2}$ & $2x$ \\\Xhline{1pt}
        \thead{$3$} & $3x$ &  $6$ \\\Xhline{1pt}
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
  \end{tasks}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please link to earlier posts when relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple and automatic solution with plain TikZ (but not a general one). You can adjust the length parameters `a`, `b`, `c` as you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=2;b=1;c=1.5;}]
\draw[line width=1.5pt,blue] 
(-1,0)-|(1+a,-b-c)-|(0,1)
(1,0)--(1,-b-c) (0,-b)--(1+a,-b)
;
\path 
(-.5,.5)     node{$\times$} ++(1,0) node{$x$}   +(.5+a/2,0) node{$3$}   
(-.5,-b/2)   node{$x$}      ++(1,0) node{$x^2$} +(.5+a/2,0) node{$3x$}
(-.5,-b-c/2) node{$2$}      ++(1,0) node{$2x$}  +(.5+a/2,0) node{$6$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with the `tabularray` package. The cells are 2cm wide and 1cm high, the rules are red and 1pt thick, but all these can be changed easily. I took away some unused stuff.

```
\documentclass[
  a5paper,
  % pagesize,11pt,% both are default and therefore not needed
  bibliography=totoc,% bibtotoc is deprecated and therefore replaced according
                     % to the warning message
  numbers=noenddot,% pointlessnumbers is deprecated and therefore replaced
                   % according to the warning message
  headings=normal,% normalheadings is deprecated and therefore replaced
                  % according to the warning message
  DIV=9,twoside=false,
  headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,% see the KOMA-Script manual
headheight=87pt,% not used, to not lower the header, but this results in a warning
footheight=52pt, % no longer needed, because the lines are not part of the footer
]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{trajan}

\usepackage{setspace}

\linespread{1.05}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}% moved according to the KOMA-Script manual, because it
                      % makes no sense before changing font an linespread.

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[%
  autoenlargeheadfoot=false,% only warn but don't change height reserved for header or footer  
  manualmark,% or maybe automark, this is not clear due to missing information
             % in the question.
  plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,% See the KOMA-Script manual for more information
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a5paper,
 total={100mm,200mm}, %not sue what this line is either.
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=35mm,
 headsep=2mm,
 }

\usepackage{tabularray} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{efbox}
\usepackage{tasks}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\newcounter{example}
\counterwithin*{example}{section}
\newlength \templgtha
\newlength \templgthb
\newlength \templgthc
\newsavebox \tempboxa
\setlength \templgthb {\textwidth}
\setlength \templgthc {\textwidth}
\addtolength \templgthc {-10pt}
\newenvironment{example}{%
  \stepcounter{example}%
  \par\vspace{5pt}\noindent
  \sbox \tempboxa{%
    \efbox[font=\normalfont\bfseries,linecolor=cyan,linewidth=.9pt]{Example~\theexample}%
  }%
  \settowidth \templgtha {\usebox \tempboxa}%
  \addtolength \templgthb {-\templgtha}%
  \usebox \tempboxa
  {\color{cyan}\vrule width\templgthb height0.9pt depth0.3pt}\par\vspace{10pt}\noindent\rmfamily
}{%
  \par\noindent
  {%
    \color{cyan}%
    \vrule width\templgthc height0.3pt depth0.9pt
    \vrule width10pt height2pt depth2pt
  }\par
}
\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \begin{tasks}
    \task $(x+2)(x+3)$
    \begin{center}

\NewColumnType{C}{Q[c,wd=2cm]}
\NewRowType{M}{Q[m,ht=1cm]}
\begin{math}
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={*3C},rowspec={*3M},
      hlines={1-Z}{red,1pt},vlines={1-Z}{red,1pt},
      vline{1}={1}{0pt},hline{1}={1}{0pt}
    }
    \times  & x   & 2 \\
       x   & x^2 & 2x \\
       3   & 3x  & 6 \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{math}

    \end{center}
  \end{tasks}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.  When I  change \NewColumnType{C}{Q[c,wd=2cm]} wd=xcm then it changes the size of both columns. Can I change the size of one of the columns? Make the column with 3 and the row with 3 longer? THank you.

Comment: You can give the `C` a parameter: `\NewColumnType{C}[1]{Q[c,wd=#1]}` and then use `C{2cm}C{2cm}C{3cm}` or so. Same with the rows.